# Websocket with okhttp3 - how to handle onPong - onPong() method not found

Tags: java, android, websocket, okhttp, ping

I'm working on an Android project implementing websocket functionality.  I want to use Ping/Pong for connectivity checks and be able to log and provide internal feedback when a ping is received.

Looking through the documentation, I haven't been able to find how Ping/Pong is handled with OKHTTP3.  All I've found is that I can set a PingInterval.

Let's say there is a connectivity problem and server sends out a ping and client doesn't receive it, or vice versa a ping is sent out to server and server doesn't receive it, how are these events handled?

How are Ping/Pong events handled in Android - Java - using okhttp3 WebSocketListener? And how can we customize the handling of those events?

I've scoured the web and asked ChatGPT, looked through javadocs. I did not find a description of event handling, all I found was one other question here on Stack Overflow, that okhttp3 handles ping/pong internally. That doesn't gives me much to work with.

Comment: okhttp does not seem keen on exposing the ping/pong events. Some users have asked for it. See: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/7370 . I think the idea is that you just worry about sending/receiving messages. Any errors in connection can be handled in the error handling methods in WebSocketListener. For your use case, your best bet for now is probably to implement application-level pings